# The value of result is not showing while running the app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was developing a BMI app using flutter and while running my app I won't get the value of 'result' printed within my app even its called within the setState.

I tried too many times but the value of BMI is not able to print on screen but when I put print() statement alongwith result its value get shown but in 'Run' terminal and the logic is also working great over there but I want to print these things on my smartphone screen.

```
Flutter--The source code is right below.
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  get float => null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var htController = TextEditingController();
    var wtController = TextEditingController();
    var result = "";
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 150,
        elevation: 22,
        shadowColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(40),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40))),
        title: const Text(
          "BMI CALCULATOR",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              color: Colors.white),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 300,
          height: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text(
                "BMI",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.blueGrey),
              ),
              const Image(
                image: NetworkImage(
                    'https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/dIrupb2X482l0AOv36KOG_sw1B91-r1SH76-ZZm9zgqmjd1NjbsUCQMLmEo1GpljQjg'),
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 21),
              TextField(
                controller: htController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: ("Please enter your height in metre."),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      width: 2,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
                  ),
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(
                    Icons.height,
                    color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  ),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: wtController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: ("Please enter your weight in kg."),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      width: 2,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
                  ),
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(
                    Icons.height,
                    color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  ),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 11,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  var wt = wtController.text.toString();
                  var ht = htController.text.toString();
                  if (wt != "" && ht != "") {
                    
                    //BMI Calculation

                    var iwt = int.parse(wt);
                    var iht = double.parse(ht);
                    var bmi = iwt / (iht * iht);
                    setState(() {

 //Here the value isn't printing on my screen of result//

                    result = "Your BMI is:-$bmi"; 

                    });
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
//Here too//
                      result = "Please fill every entry first.";

                    });
                  }
                },
                child: const Text('Calculate'),
              ),
              Text(

//Here I called the result//

                result,
                style:
                    const TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont define variable inside build method, else it will recreate the variables on every build that will be trigger by `setState`.

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  get float => null;
  var htController = TextEditingController();
  var wtController = TextEditingController();
  var result = "";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```